# An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the PutAccountDetails operation: None

Tags: command-line-interface, amazon-ses

My AWS SES from the console has been denied twice i guess and i tried to get it done from CLI with the below command

aws sesv2 put-account-details \

--production-access-enabled 
--mail-type TRANSACTIONAL 
--website-url  https://loganairportcar.com 
--use-case-description "(1)How do you plan to build or acquire your mailing list?
Ans:- We acquire the mailing list from a contact form, inquiry form, user registration form from https://www.loganairportcar.com/reservation and https://www.loganairportcar.com/contact . From the website end only, when user fill up the forms and submit the form to the website.

(2) How do you plan to handle bounces and complaints?
Ans:- For bounces and complaints we are going to use the AWS SNS.

(3)How can recipients opt out of receiving email from you?
Ans:- We will send the unsubscribe link at the bottom of email with the unsubscribe message explaining detail. After unsubscribe link click from the user end we will remove that email from the subscribed list.

(4)How did you choose the sending rate or sending quota that you specified in this request?
Ans:- As per our email service usages the sending rate or sending quota that the AWS provide will be enough to us at the moment." 
--additional-contact-email-addresses info@loganairportcar.com 
--contact-language EN

At the final stage it gives me below error
An error occurred (ConflictException) when calling the PutAccountDetails operation: None

How to fix that

Comment: any news on this issue?